# Can you apply the Residue Theorem to real domains?

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been reading about the residue theorem lately, and I know that you can apply it to solve real integrals by building a domain with one edge on the real axis representing the integral you want to solve. My question is, can you apply it to a simply connected real domain? Like if you were integrating around the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$, could you then apply the Residue Theorem to your integrand there?

Just curious, couldn't get a straight answer although it seems to me like you could.

Edit: Now I'm thinking maybe you can't, since a domain in $\mathbb{R}$ would just be an interval in $\mathbb{C}$, right? And so having a singularity on that interval would make it not simply connected.

Comment: I don't think so. A function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ would look on the complex plane  always like a line on the real axis. The residue theorem works for closed contours but a non-complex real function cannot be a closed contour.